# Как работает стек вызова функций при рекурсии?

Tags: javascript

Написал простую рекурсию (работает как задумано):

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,10];
let result = 0;
let i = 0;
const sum = mas => {
  if(i < mas.length){
    result += mas[i];
    i++;
    return sum(mas);
  } else {
    return result;
  }
}
console.log(sum(arr));
```

Начал играться. Первое что я сделал это убрал `return` из первого `if` и дописал `console.log(result);` после вызова самой себя:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,10];
let result = 0;
let i = 0;
const sum = mas => {
  if(i < mas.length){
    result += mas[i];
    i++;
    sum(mas);
    console.log(result);
  } else {
    return result;
  }
}
console.log(sum(arr));
```

Сначало результат меня удивил, но потом я понял, что сначало вызвалась 4 раза функция, которая посчитала сумму, и только потом отработал `console.log(result);` так же 4 раза. Но тут в конце я увидел `undefined`. Чуть поменяв код, я получил результат:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,10];
let result = 0;
let i = 0;
const sum = mas => {
  if(i < mas.length){
    result += mas[i];
    i++;
    sum(mas);
    console.log(result);
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(sum(arr));
```

А теперь вопрос: почему в `else` `return`, именно`return`, возвращает `undefined`, так как если поставить перед ним `console.log(result);`, в консоле мы увидим корректный результат?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рассмотрим второй пример, строку

```
console.log(sum(arr));
```

Что выдаст лог? Конечно, результат работы функции `sum(arr)`

А что делает функция `sum(arr)`

```
const sum = mas => {
    if(i < mas.length){      // <-- i == 0, проваливаемся в if
        result += mas[i];    // <-- прибавили к result i-ый элемент массива
        i++;                 // <-- увеличили i
        sum(mas);            // <-- запустили рекурсивно функцию
        console.log(result); // <-- залогировали result и...
                             // <-- ...ничего не вернули
    } else {
        return result;       // <-- это не выполнится, так как зашли в if
    }
}
```

В *JavaScript* функция всегда [возвращает результат](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics#vozvrat-znacheniya). Если не указать `return` функция вернет `undefined`.

Этот `undefined` и выводит `console.log(sum(arr));`

---

В третьем примере функция `sum(arr)` вернет результат

```
const sum = mas => {
    if(i < mas.length){
        result += mas[i];
        i++;
        sum(mas);
        console.log(result); // <-- выполнение функции не закончено
    }
    return result;           // <-- нужно еще выполнить эту строку, вернуть `result`
}
```

Comment: Но на этапе, когда `i` равно 5 — заходит. Почему нет `undefined`?

Comment: Когда `i` равно 5, не  выполняется ветка `if`, соответственно выполняется ветка `else`, которая вернет `result` равный `16`. После чего функция `sum()` отдаёт управление вверх по рекурсии. Происходит логирование `result`, а так как переменная `result` находится в глобальном контексте, она видна и в контексте функции `sum()`. `sum()` логирует глобальный `result` и возвращает `undefined` функции `sum()`, вызвавшей её. Та в свою очередь логирует глобальный `result` и возвращает `undefined` и т.д.